# Drupal 6 + Imagecache + nginx = no images

Tags: drupal, nginx, drupal-6

I've installed Drupal 6 on nginx, but I have problem with imagecache - viewing any image generates blank screen.

PHP GD installed:

```
# php -m | grep gd
gd
```

777 on sites folder and everything in it:

```
ls -l | grep sites
drwxrwxrwx  4 nginx nginx      4096 Jan 12 23:36 sites
```

vhost.conf:

```
location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
            # You have 2 options here
            # For D7 and above:
            # Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
            #rewrite ^ /index.php;
            # For Drupal 6 and bwlow:
            # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
            # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    # This is for D6
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ {
    # This is for D7 and D8
    #location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }
```

There are errors in Drupal log:

```
imagecache  2014-01-13 21:29    404: Unable to find low.jpg guest
```

No errors in nginx error.log (only in access.log = 404) or php error log.

Files exists in

```
/sites/default/files/
```

imagecache_sample.png is created correctly after opening imagecache module.

Any ideas?